# Mockito: verify that a method was not called with specific parameter type

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I wanted to test with Mockito that a method was not called with a specific parameter type with this simplified test:

```
@Test
public void testEm() {
    EntityManager emMock = Mockito.mock(EntityManager.class);
    emMock.persist("test");

    Mockito.verify(emMock, Mockito.never()).persist(Matchers.any(Integer.class));

}
```

Surprisingly this test failed with the following output:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.NeverWantedButInvoked: 
entityManager.persist(<any>);
Never wanted here:
-> at com.sg.EmTest.testEm(EmTest.java:21)
But invoked here:
-> at com.sg.EmTest.testEm(EmTest.java:19)
```

I expected this test to fail only when the persist method is called with an Integer parameter, but it fails with String as well.

Why doesn't it work and how could I test it?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `persist()` method takes an argument as `Object` and when you select `any(Integer.class)` will be converted to any object, so it will fail because you call it using `String`.

The best method here to specify the argument using `eq()`, like this

```
Mockito.verify(emMock, Mockito.never()).persist(Matchers.eq(Integer.valueOf(1)));
```

---

Or use `ArgumentCaptor` to capture the arguments and assert them

```
@Test
public void testEm() {
    // Arrange
    EntityManager emMock = Mockito.mock(EntityManager.class);
    ArgumentCaptor<Object> captor =  ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Object.class);  

    // Act
    emMock.persist("test");

    // Assert
    verify(emMock).persit(captor.catpure());
    Object val = captor.getValue();
    Assert....
}
```

[Oracle doc#persist()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#persist-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: Thank You very much, it helped a lot. In the final solution I used it:

    `Mockito.verify(emMock, Mockito.never()).persist(Matchers.isA(Integer.class));`

Comment: I find that strange. Why would `any(Integer.class)` match anything other than an `Integer` argument, regardless of the target method's parameter type?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `not` matcher http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#not(org.hamcrest.Matcher)

```
Matchers.not(Matchers.any(Integer.class))
```